# React native access to the reload method dev-tools

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, debugging, react-native

Is there any way to access you have methods of react native dev tools?

I would like to make sure that through a button that is in the app being debugged, the reload method that is seen in the image is called.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using mac, there is a lib called **Frappe** ([GitHub link](https://github.com/niftylettuce/frappe)).
2. Also you can use this command in shell:

`adb shell input keyevent 82`

3. And finally, take a look at this article which explains:

> [How to Extending React Native’s Dev Menu](https://medium.com/capriza-engineering/extending-react-natives-dev-menu-c084fc93717d)

Maybe you can inspire and gather some useful info from that!